# Display Gallery Grid View for Advanced Custom Fields Wordpress

Tags: php, image, gridview, advanced-custom-fields, image-gallery

I have created a gallery field group in ACF as seen in the image below.

[image: Gallery field group] To display this on my wordpress page I have added the following code to the php file.

```
<?php 

$images = get_field('employee_testimonial_gallery');

if( $images ): ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
        <li>
                 <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

            <p><?php echo $image['caption']; ?></p>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>


</ul>
```

However the end result is displaying as a list

[image: list display]

and I need the images to display as a grid like below

[image: grid display]

I've read all the documentation on ACF and it seems to be a general issue. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css to list it as like grid. Before start just add a class to your output html markup.

```
<ul class="gal-grid">
<?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
    <li>
             <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

        <p><?php echo $image['caption']; ?></p>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Then after this markup changes apply bellow css,

```
ul.gal-grid li{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

ul.gal-grid li:last-child{
margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Niamul thanks for your help, nearly there but where do I put the css code? I have put it i n my stylesheet and it is displaying in a grid but it is showing in left alignment how do I center this block?

Comment: Can I get your site link so I can help you more there ?